# RxJava with zip operator run everything in the same thread

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I would try to do 2 func in the same time

```
fun getDataSync() {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            Observable.zip(
                repository.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                repository.getData3().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                { a, b -> a + b }
            )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        _data.value = it
                    },
                    {
                        _data.value = 0
                    }
                )
        )
    }

class FakeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor() : FakeRepository {
    override fun getData(): Observable<Int> {
        println("test2k200: getData " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        return Observable.just(1)
    }
    override fun getData3(): Observable<Int> {
        println("test2k200: getData3 " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        return Observable.just(3)
    }
```

but it seems like everything work on the same main thread
in the console I can see:

"getData main"
and after 10 sec
"getData3 main"

repository with defer:

```
class FakeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor() : FakeRepository {
    override fun getData(): Single<Int> {
        println("test2k200: getData " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        return Single.defer { Single.just(1) }
    }
  
    override fun getData3(): Single<Int> {
        println("test2k200: getData3 " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        return Single.defer { Single.just(3) }
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `getData` on the main thread which then prints right there, before it even going into RxJava. This is a common beginner misunderstanding: returning an `Observable` doesn't mean everything inside the method will now run upon subscription. You need to `defer` or `fromCallable` and put the code inside their lambdas.

Comment: I edited post and showed how it look with defer, I was trying it with defer but I got the same result - main thread and working sequentially instead in parallel

Comment: Again, your print code executes before RxJava gets involved. Put those into the defer too.

Comment: something like that: 

return Single.defer {
            println("test2k200: getData " + Thread.currentThread().name)
            Thread.sleep(10000)
            Single.just(1)
        }

 ?